# Can not send Python message via socket to Java

Tags: java, python, sockets

I am trying to send a message from Python to Java by using sockets.

Java socket code is found here.
https://www.dukascopy.com/wiki/en/development/strategy-api/practices/socket-connection

Python code is here.

```
import socket

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 7001))
clientsocket.send(b'BUY')
clientsocket.close()
```

I run the python code after activate Java program.
However, I got an below error.

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)                                                                         
at dukascopy.strategies.SimpleSocketStrategy$TransferSocketServer.run(SimpleSocketStrategy.java:77)             
at dukascopy.strategies.SimpleSocketStrategy$TransferSocketServer.handleConnection(SimpleSocketStrategy.java:94)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)                                                             
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)                                                   
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)                                     
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)                                          
java.io.EOFException
```

Why I accepted these error? Thank you very much.

【Edit】
This error happended when

```
clientsocket.connect(('localhost', 7001))
```

is executed.

Comment: ObjectInputStream is for reading serialized *Java objects,* not regular data.  You should be using `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII))` to read the text sent by your Python program.

Comment: I can print out "BUY" comment! There is another error, but I have to solve it with myself. Anyway, Thank you for your pointing out and solution!